# Injecting variables into iframe in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento

I have an iFrame tag with variables I am trying to dynamically populate with a javascript function on a Magento web store. I found some code on this Magento blog [1](https://sherocommerce.com/commission-junction-how-to-get-it-to-work-on-magento-draft/), but it seems to be a bit out-dated, and it doesn't specify where in the Magento files I am supposed to insert the functions.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
echo '<script type="text/javascript">' private function _getOrderProductsList($order) {
    $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
    $purchasedSkus = array();
    $count_orderItems = count($orderItems);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count_orderItems; $i++) { $item=$orderItems[$i]; $product_type=$item->getProductType();

    $price = $item->getPrice();

    if($price>”0.00″)
    {

    $purchasedSkus[$i] = array(
    ‘ITEM’ => $orderItems[$i][‘sku’],
    ‘QTY’ => number_format($orderItems[$i][‘qty_ordered’],0), // no decimals
    ‘AMT’ => number_format($orderItems[$i][‘price’],2) // 2 decimal places

    // Per C.J, the following line should be commented out.

    // ‘DCNT’ => number_format(abs($orderItems[$i][‘discount_amount’]),2)
    );

    } // end if if price > 0.00
    }
    }; '</script>'  // end for statement?>

<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success */ ?>
<div class="checkout-success">
<iframe height="1" width="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.emjcd.com/tags/c?containerTagId=[ContainerID]&TYPE=[TYPE]&CID=[CID]&AMOUNT=[Subtotal]&ITEMx=[ItemSku]&AMTx=[AmountofItem]&QTYx=[Quantity]&DCNTx=[ItemDiscount]&OID=[OID]&DISCOUNT=[DiscountAmount]&CURRENCY=USD&COUPON=[couponcode]&CJEVENT=[INBOUNDVALUE]&CHANNEL=[CHANNEL]&CHANNEL_TS=[TIMESTAMP]" name="cj_conversion" ></iframe>
    <?php if ($block->getOrderId()):?>
        <?php if ($block->getCanViewOrder()) :?>
            <p><?= __('Your order number is: %1.', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="order-number"><strong>%s</strong></a>', $block->escapeHtml($block->getViewOrderUrl()), $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId()))) ?></p>
        <?php  else :?>
            <p><?= __('Your order # is: <span>%1</span>.', $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId())) ?></p>
        <?php endif;?>
            <p><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('We\'ll email you an order confirmation with details and tracking info.') ?></p>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?= $block->getAdditionalInfoHtml() ?>

    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <a class="action primary continue" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getContinueUrl() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Continue Shopping') ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```